# Tab Navigator is not working on expo standalone android app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on react native project using expo framework. Everything is working fine but when I make builds using expo then on android app bottom navigation is not working instead app restarts when I navigate towards bottom navigation

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('TabNavigator', {screen: 'Details' })
```

Comment: would you mind sharing the whole code for your `TabNavigator` structure? Also, I believe you are trying to navigate to a screen called `Details`, in which case, you can simply do `this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')` Referring to https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#navigate `navigation.navigate()` takes two arguments, the first one being the name of the route and the second being the parameters you want passed to the screen you're navigating to.

Comment: hey @Harrison. Thanksn for replying. TabNavigator is basically Tab Navigation while Details is its tab.

Comment: my structure is working fine on ios and expo client. Issue is only on android apk

Comment: @Harrison can you please assist if I share code repo with you?